# Application crashes only when launched from inittab on busybox

Tags: c, linux, tcp, busybox

I'm writing an application for an embedded busybox system that allows TCP connections, then sends out messages to all connected clients. It works perfectly when I telnet to the box and run the application from a shell prompt, but I have problems when it is launched from the inittab. It will launch and I can connect to the application with one client. It successfully sends one message out to that client, then crashes. It will also crash if I connect a second client before any messages are sent out. Again, everything works perfectly if I launch it from a shell prompt instead.

The following errors are what comes up in the log:

```
<11>Jan  1 00:02:49 tmmpd.bin: ERROR: recvMessage failed, recv IO error 
<11>Jan  1 00:02:49 tmmpd.bin: Some other LTK TCP error 103. Closing connection 10 
<11>Jan  1 00:02:49 tmmpd.bin: ERROR: recvMessage failed, recv IO error 
<11>Jan  1 00:02:49 tmmpd.bin: Some other LTK TCP error 103. Closing connection 10
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was testing a bit in `arm-qemu` and `busybox`, and I was able to start a script as user test to run in background.

I have created a new user "test":

```
buildroot-dir> cat etc/passwd
test:x:1000:1000:Linux User,,,:/home/test:/bin/sh
```

Created a simple `testscript.sh`:

```
target_system> cat /home/test/testscript.sh
#!/bin/sh

while :
do
    echo "still executing in bg"
    sleep 10
done
```

To my `/etc/init.d/rcS` I added a startup command for it:

```
#!/bin/sh
mount -t proc none /proc
mount -t sysfs none /sys
/sbin/mdev -s

/bin/su test -c /home/test/testscript.sh& # < Added this
```

Now when I start the system, the script will run in the background, and when I grep for the process it has been started as user `test` (default root user is just `0`):

```
target_system> ps aux | grep testscript
496 test    0:00 sh -c home/test/testscript.sh
507 test    0:00 {testscript.sh} /bin/sh home/test/testscript.sh
```

Comment: I tried this, but no luck. It doesn't seem to launch at all when I try and use su in the inittab. In fact, I'm not even sure su is available on this busybox implementation...it's pretty stripped down since it's an embedded device.

Comment: @DrRocket I hacked around a bit, and now have a working solution that is working on a test qemu system that is running arm kernel and busybox rootfs, give that a try!